# How can I change form field values after calling the is_valid() method?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How can I change form field values after calling the `is_valid()` method?

I am trying to alter the field `u_id` after I validate the data with `form.is_valid` (this is required). I can alter the data, even display it in the `HttpResponse`, but I cannot write it into my Postgresql DB. Any ideas?

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = Product

class Product(models.Model):
    p_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    u_id = models.CharField(max_length=80)

def uploadImage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = ProductForm(request.POST, prefix="product")
        if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
            form1.cleaned_data['uid']='12134324231'
            form1.save()

            return HttpResponse(form1.cleaned_data['p_name'])

    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form, 'form1': form1},            RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Save the model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) with `commit=False`, then modify the instance before saving to the database.

```
if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
    instance = form1.save(commit=False)
    instance.uid = '12134324231'
    instance.save()
```

If `form1` had any many-to-many relationships, you would have to call the `save_m2m` method to save the many-to-many form data. See the docs for full details.

Comment: As of Django 2.0 when commit=False you might also need to save m2m fields. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: @Mashakal that's not new in Django 2.0, you've always had to call `save_m2m` to save many-to-many form data.

Answer (score 3):

From [Overriding clean() on a ModelFormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-clean-on-a-modelformset).

> Also note that by the time you reach this step, individual model instances have already been created for each Form. **Modifying a value in form.cleaned_data is not sufficient to affect the saved value.** If you wish to modify a value in ModelFormSet.clean() you must **modify form.instance**:

```
from django.forms import BaseModelFormSet

class MyModelFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(MyModelFormSet, self).clean()

        for form in self.forms:
            name = form.cleaned_data['name'].upper()
            form.cleaned_data['name'] = name
            # update the instance value.
            form.instance.name = name
```

So what you should do is:

```
if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
        form1.instance.uid ='12134324231'
        form1.save()
```